# I tried the python code using keras and i got a warning

Tags: python, windows, keras, jupyter-notebook, user-warning

While executing the line bellow

```py
model.add(Dense(input_dim=23,init="random_uniform",activation="relu",output_dim=12))
```

I get this warning:

```
UserWarning: Update your `Dense` call to the Keras 2 API: `Dense(input_dim=23, activation="relu", units=12, kernel_initializer="random_uniform")
```

What is causing this warning?

Comment: Please add to your questin what tensorflow version do you use.

Comment: 1.14.0 is  the tensorflow version

Comment: Always good to reference what resources or doc you tried to find answers to your question but were unable to find anything.